# Unit Testing, iOS, DTXProxyChannel error 1

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing

I sometimes start to get the following error

> 2017-04-02 18:55:22.645937+0200 Stamps[730:111791] Connection peer
>   refused channel request for
>   "dtxproxy:XCTestDriverInterface:XCTestManager_IDEInterface"; channel
>   canceled  Failed to run tests: The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (DTXProxyChannel error 1.)

Last time, when this happened, I just did some random actions with clean my project, remove derived data etc., and it was fixed. Now, it happens again - just after a start of the app, it closes and log contains this error.

What does it mean and is there any workaround here?

I use XCode 8.3, Swift 3.1, test on device 6s with 10.3 installed.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Surprisingly, to fix this, I just replugged my iPhone to another port

Comment: I didn't try connecting and disconnecting first, but this certainly did work. +1

Comment: I did try connecting and disconnecting first, and that didn't work, but this did.  quite odd.

Comment: Thanks, It works, do you have an idea the reason for that

Comment: Worked for me too thanks. Man I spent almost a day puling my hair.

Comment: I'm in disbelief. I disconnected/reconnected, rebooted both my iPhone and my MacBook, and this was the only thing that worked.

Comment: Had this problem with simulators run by the xcode bots. Saw this solution and did a similar thing with Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings, which solved it.

Comment: I've no idea why this solution works for me. XCode is a miracle. Thanks for saving my day, hero.